# How do I spilt list with dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

Assume I have a list like:

var numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5"];

I would like a list spilt list:

var numbers = ["1","1",
"2","3",
"1","2","3",
"1","2","3","4",
"1","2","3","4","5"];

what's a good way to do this with dart?

Comment: `final l = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
final l2 = List.generate(l.length, (i) => l.sublist(0, i + 1)).expand((i) => i);`

Comment: or `List.generate(l.length, (i) => l.sublist(0, i + 1)).flattened` if you import `import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky to know what you want, because your expected output does not actually line up with what you seem to want. I will assume psink was correct in guessing and you want that:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final input = ["A","B","C","D","E"]; 
  
  final output = List.generate(input.length, (i) => input.sublist(0, i + 1)).expand((i) => i).toList();
  
  print(input.runtimeType);
  print(input);
  
  print(output.runtimeType);
  print(output);
}
```

That in dartpad generates

> JSArray

> [A, B, C, D, E]

> JSArray

> [A, A, B, A, B, C, A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D, E]

Which hopefully is what you need. Thanks to psink for the actual code.